# What is the name of this type of figure?

Tags: ngs, visualization, genomics, figure-explanation, genetics

[This figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AADACL3) comes from [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AADACL3).

[image]

I googled "gene location figure" and "gene location plot", none gets similar results. I also tried search by image, none of the results is close.

so, what is the name of this type of figure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of visualization showing the banding patterns of chromosomes are called "[chromosome ideograms](https://www.dna-rainbow.org/ideograms)".

You can use for example [IdeoViz](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/IdeoViz) in R to generate them.

Answer (score 3):

Such a figure is called ideogram, or chromosome ideogram.